# how to make list comparable with other lists

Tags: python, list, compare

i have this code:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('C:\\Users\\ntonto\\Documents\\Currencies\\BTC-USD.csv', encoding='utf-8=sig') as csvfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    count = 0
    fsa = []
    for row in r:
        count = count + 1
        fsa.append(row['Open'])
        if count > 10:
            continue

with open('C:\\Users\\ntonto\\Documents\\Currencies\\BTC-USD.csv', encoding='utf-8=sig') as csvfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    count = 0
    fsb = []
    for row in r:
        count = count + 1
        fsb.append(row['Close'])
        if count > 10:
            continue


kol = []
for i in range(len(fsa)):
    if fsa[i] < fsb[i]:
        kol.append('1')
    else:
        kol.append('0')

start = 0
end = len(fsa)
j = [ ]
for x in range(start, end, 6):
    m = fsb[x:x+6]
    t = kol[x:x+6]
    if m[0] < m[-1]:
        t.append('up')
    else:
        t.append('down')
    j.append(t)

jol = []
counter = Counter(tuple(j) for j in j)
for members, count, in counter.items():
    print(list(members), count)
```

which presents this output:

```
['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up'] 2
['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up'] 1
['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down'] 2
['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up'] 3
['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up'] 2
['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down'] 2
['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up'] 2
['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up'] 1
['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up'] 2
['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up'] 1
['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down'] 1
['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down'] 1
['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up'] 1
```

i am trying to get the output to be presented as a list in this manner:

```
[['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 2],
['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1],
['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 2],
['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 3],
['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 2],
['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2],
['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 2],
['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1],
['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 2],
['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1],
['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1],
['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 1],
['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 1]]
```

the reason is because i want to be able to use this code:

```
def find_list(list1, list2):
    index = -1
    occ = 0
    for i, l in enumerate(list2):
        if l[:len(list1)] == list1:
            if l[-1] > occ:
                index = i
                occ = l[-1]
    if index == -1:
        return "The 1st list doesn't appear in the 2nd one."
    else:
        return f"The 1st list appears in the 2nd one at index {index} with a number of occurences equal to {occ}."


print(find_list(listB, listA))
```

I to be able to compare the two lists and find a similar list in the list of lists.
i have been trying various methods but non of the ones I tried work and now I am stuck here. I truly hope i was clear enough on what it is i want but in case i was not, what i want to do is to be able to use a list made up of multiple lists to find a specific list for example:

to find this list:

```
['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

in this list of lists:

```
 [['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 2],
    ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1],
    ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 2],
    ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 3],
    ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 2],
    ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2],
    ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 2],
    ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1],
    ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 2],
    ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1],
    ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1],
    ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 1],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 1]]
```

Comment: Why are you looping over the same file twice? You can append to both lists in the same loop.

Comment: `if count > 10: continue` doesn't do anything useful. You don't have to tell a loop to continue, it repeats automatically. Maybe you meant `break` so it would stop after 10 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
for members, count, in counter.items():
    print(list(members), count)
```

to

```
for members, count, in counter.items():
    print([*members, count])
```

This will spread the tuple into the first list elements, and then use `count` as the next element.

Comment: Okay thanks this seems to print the output in the manner i want it printed

Comment: however i am still unable to compare the lists as i get this error:     if l[:len(list1)] == list1:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: how can i overcome this? please assist me

Comment: What is `list2`? Your code expects it to be a list of lists, but the error indicates that it's a list of integers.

Comment: You should be using `listA.append([*members, count])`